# outcome of Running two dockerfiles

Tags: docker

I have been learning Docker for a while now and i got asked the following question recently:

> What do you think will happen if you download an image with a docker
>   file to your machine, then create a new Dockerfile and try to 'docker
>   run' the image in order to create a container? Which Dockerfile will
>   be used by Docker?

I am not entirely sure what the answer to the above question is, can anybody tell me what would be the correct answer to the above question be ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to try to answer as best as I understood the question.

I don't think this situation can happen because the `Dockerfile` is solely use during the build of the image.

Once you ran `docker build .` given a Dockerfile, the image is self sufficient.
Even, it is not possible to `docker run` a Dockerfile directly. It has to be an image already built (Tools that help you orchestrate that in one step, such as Docker Compose, don't change that fact).

So if you try to run an image you just pulled, while you have a Dockerfile in your directory, basically nothing wrong will happen. A new container will run using the specified image and that's all

Comment: let me put it this way, suppose i `pull` a docker image , now i have the image locally , now i create a new Dockerfile and do a `run` in order to create a container .. which Dockerfile will be used by Docker ? (there is no build going on here !!)

Comment: The Dockerfile has nothing to do with ```run``` that is the key :) The argument you pass to ```docker run``` is the image name. If you haven't built a new image using your new Dockerfile. The Dockerfile will properly be ignored and the image you gave as argument will be used (Image be available locally or not)

Comment: ```run``` create a container from an image. ```build``` create an image from a Dockerfile

Comment: Which dockerile will be used by docker ? thats my question .. please read my question correctly !

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand your question then. I'm sorry. Docker ```run``` won't use any Dockerfile. Never. Only images. Only ```build``` does (And build will pick a file actually named ```Dockerfile``` or one specified as argument with ```-f```. You cannot mechanically pass two Dockerfiles)

Answer (score 0):

Do keep in mind that there is only one `Dockerfile` from which you can build an image, there is no point of having two Dockerfiles in one directory.

When you download a Docker image, It's Dockerfile is not downloaded but the image is added to your local registry. That image can be used to further extend the Docker image you downloaded using `FROM` in Dockerfile or directly run containers using the image.